# Is there a Safari extension to hide results from a Google search?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, safari-extensions

IMHO one of the most underrated browser extension is Chrome’s [Personal Blocklist (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef). It hides results in your Google search results after you have blocked certain domains them once. Is there a similar extension for Safari? [Personal-Search-Result-Blocker](https://github.com/j4yd0rs3y/Personal-Search-Result-Blocker), an extension hosted on GitHub, doesn’t work.

Comment: Well I could not find one, let us know if you do.

Answer (score 1):

I found this recommendation, uBlacklist, from Reddit: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ublacklist-for-safari/id1547912640

> uBlacklist for Safari is a Search Engine filter. Help you improve the quality of your search results.
>
> Features:
>
> - Support Bing, DuckDuckGo, Ecosia (partially) and Startpage.com
> - Blocks sites you specify from appearing in search engine results
> - Block sites flexibly using match patterns and regular expressions
> - Subscribe to public blacklists keep it up to date